# KeyError when adding objects to SQLAlchemy association object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables, `tablet` and `correspondent`:

```
class Correspondent(db.Model, GlyphMixin):
    # PK column and tablename etc. come from the mixin
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    # association proxy
    tablets = association_proxy('correspondent_tablets', 'tablet')

    def __init__(self, name, tablets=None):
        self.name = name
        if tablets:
            self.tablets = tablets


class Tablet(db.Model, GlyphMixin):
    # PK column and tablename etc. come from the mixin
    area = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    # association proxy
    correspondents = association_proxy('tablet_correspondents', 'correspondent')

    def __init__(self, area, correspondents=None):
        self.area = area
        if correspondents:
            self.correspondents = correspondents


class Tablet_Correspondent(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "tablet_correspondent"
    tablet_id = db.Column("tablet_id",
        db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("tablet.id"), primary_key=True)
    correspondent_id = db.Column("correspondent_id",
        db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("correspondent.id"), primary_key=True)
    # relations
    tablet = db.relationship(
        "Tablet",
        backref="tablet_correspondents",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        single_parent=True)
    correspondent = db.relationship(
        "Correspondent",
        backref="correspondent_tablets",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        single_parent=True)

    def __init__(self, tablet=None, correspondent=None):
        self.tablet = tablet
        self.correspondent = correspondent
```

I can add records to `tablet` and `correspondent`, and doing e.g. `Tablet.query.first().correspondents` simply returns an empty list, as you would expect. If I manually insert a row into my `tablet_correspondent` table using existing tablet and correspondent IDs, the list is populated, again as you would expect.

However, if I try to do

```
cor = Correspondent.query.first()
tab = Tablet.query.first()
tab.correspondents.append(cor)
```

I get:

```
KeyError: 'tablet_correspondents'
```

I'm pretty sure I'm leaving out something fairly elementary here.

Comment: I think your `__tablename__ = "tablet_correspondent"` is wrong. Shouldn't it be `tablet_correspondents` (with an `s` at the end)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The **problem** with your code is in the `.__init__` method. If you are to `debug-watch/print()` the parameters, you will notice that the parameter `tablet` is actually an instance of `Correspondent`:

```
class Tablet_Correspondent(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, tablet=None, correspondent=None):
        print "in __init__: ", tablet, correspondent
        self.tablet = tablet
        self.correspondent = correspondent
```

The reason for this is the way SA creates new values. From documentation [Creation of New Values](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#creation-of-new-values):

> When a list `append()` event (or set `add()`, dictionary `__setitem__()`, or
>   scalar assignment event) is intercepted by the association proxy, it
>   instantiates a new instance of the “intermediary” object using its
>   constructor, passing as a single argument the given value.

In your case when you call `tab.correspondents.append(cor)`, the `Tablet_Correspondent.__init__` is called with single argument `cor`.

**Solution?** If you will only be adding `Correspondents` to the `Tablet`, then just switch the parameters in the `__init__`. In fact, remove the second parameter completely.
If, however, you will also be using `cor.tablets.append(tab)`, then you need to explicitely use the `creator` argument to the `association_proxy` as explained in the documentation linked to above:

```
class Tablet(db.Model, GlyphMixin):
    # ...
    correspondents = association_proxy('tablet_correspondents', 'correspondent', creator=lambda cor: Tablet_Correspondent(correspondent=cor))

class Correspondent(db.Model, GlyphMixin):
    # ...
    tablets = association_proxy('correspondent_tablets', 'tablet', creator=lambda tab: Tablet_Correspondent(tablet=tab))
```

Answer (score 2):

Like van said, the problem stay in the `__init__` method of the [Association Object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects).

In fact, if Tablet or Correspondent classes don't define an `__init__` method or don't pass any parameter, the solution doesn't work (no argument expected).

I found an alternative solution. It's easy to detect which class has to be proxied, so it can be assigned to the right field (and still work on adding more associations):

```
class Tablet_Correspondent(db.Model):

    # ...

    def __init__(self, proxied=None):
        if type(proxied) is Tablet:
            self.tablet = proxied
        elif type(proxied) is Correspondent:
            self.correspondent = proxied
```

Comment: Nice way to avoid using lambdas. Thanks!