# Key error on backref when try to setup many to many Association Object

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to setup a basic many-to-many relationship using sqlalchemy and can't pin down what I'm doing wrong.  Essentially, I have a table of Users and a table of Offers (basically, something like Groupon).  Users can respond to many offers, and offers can be sent to many users.  I've been using this section of the [sqlalchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) but clearly I'm doing something wrong.
Here is the relevant section of my code:

```
class Offer(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'offers'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
    users = association_proxy('user_offers', 'user')

    def __init__(self, title, description):
        self.title = title
        self.description = description

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, index=True, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, email):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email.lower()

class UserOfferResponse(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_offer_responses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    offer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('offers.id'))
    response = Column(String)
    created_at = Column(DateTime)

    offer = relationship(Offer,
            backref=backref("user_offers",
                            cascade="all, delete-orphan")
        )
    user = relationship("User")

    def __init__(self, offer=None, user=None, response="", created_at=datetime.datetime.now()):
        self.response = response
        self.offer = offer
        self.user = user
        self.created_at = created_at
```

Using the code above, I can create an Offer and a User, but if I try to associate the two (`offer.users.append(user)`) I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/scottmorse/.virtualenvs/WhereItsApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 224, in __set__
    instance_dict(instance), value, None)
  File "/Users/scottmorse/.virtualenvs/WhereItsApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 802, in set
    value = self.fire_replace_event(state, dict_, value, old, initiator)
  File "/Users/scottmorse/.virtualenvs/WhereItsApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 824, in fire_replace_event
    self._replace_token or self._init_append_or_replace_token())
  File "/Users/scottmorse/.virtualenvs/WhereItsApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1153, in emit_backref_from_scalar_set_event
    child_impl = child_state.manager[key].impl
KeyError: 'user_offers'
```

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks for reading.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and I hacked it by adding the relation direct to the association object in your case UserOfferResponse. My answer does not seem right though its simular to what https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky does in models.py . See the User - Follows relationship as an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer here: [KeyError when adding objects to SQLAlchemy association object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091491/keyerror-when-adding-objects-to-sqlalchemy-association-object/11116291#11116291)

Because I was trying to add a user to the offer's list, I needed to either 1) make sure that the User is the first item passed to the UserOfferResponse constructor (because that is how it will be called by the association_proxy, or 2) add an explicit 'creator' parameter to the association_proxy.

I chose option 2, as it allows me to work in "both directions".  Thanks for reading!